# SQL Server : move data to another table with additional data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table which contains 6000 member data on it. I need some specific data from that table. I can move this to my table but its kinda complicated.
My new member system work like, when a member register in it gave this member a unique 6-8 digit id/token and create 2 another tables with this member's token in it.

I mean first table be like,

```
[inID][stMail][stPass][stToken]  .. etc
```

This token is the key of my another tables

```
[stToken][stName][stSurname][stAdress][stPhone]...etc..
```

While I move this data to my tables I need to create 2 more tables which has same token as the original table.

So it looks like

```
[1][mail][pass][123123]

[123123][name][surname][address][phone]
```

How can I do that in SQL or asp.net C#?

I try to select all data from the old table, take the string values what i need and write down to my new tables but after 8 hours its only write 200 member's data which is odd.

Sorry for my interesting english.

Comment: all data are in one table in your current database and you need to generate the token . am I right? plese give me the sructure of your current table

Comment: @Alipishkari i want to move specific data to another table with additional given token. and create 2 other tables with this members token so i can reach any member's data from another tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below. In this case I am assuming you have a logic for generating `token string`. For now I'll simply substitute that token with say a `row_number()` value.  This approach uses a temp table.

```
-- create a #temp table
create table #temp
(
  [inID] int, 
  [stMail] varchar(20),
  [stPass] varchar(20),
  [stToken] varchar(20),
  [stName] varchar(20),
  [stSurname] varchar(20),
  [stAdress] varchar(20),
  [stPhone] varchar(20)
)
--insert values in #temp table
insert into #temp
select
  [inID]     ,
  [stMail]   ,
  [stPass]   ,
  row_number() over (order by inID,stMail) as [stToken]  ,
  [stName]   ,
  [stSurname],
  [stAdress] ,
  [stPhone]  
 from t

--copy from #temp table into t1 and t2 tables
 insert into t1
 select 
  [inID]     ,
  [stMail]   ,
  [stPass]   ,
  [stToken]  
 from #temp

 insert into t2
 select 
  [stToken]  ,
  [stName]   ,
  [stSurname],
  [stAdress] ,
  [stPhone]  
 from #temp

--don't forget to drop the #temp table
 drop table #temp
```

see demo sql fiddle link here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/185eb/4

Comment: i actually go for the long way with c#. first create a new table with old values and additional unique token. then create a new table with the particular users. then after that compare the names and when they match i add the first table's user token to second one. and it goes like that. its goin' pretty well actually. thanks for the answer btw. i try this too